# Terragrunt - how to deal with raw JSON

Tags: terraform, okta, terragrunt

I'm using terragrunt to manage okta resources. I'm using [okta_user](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/okta/okta/latest/docs/resources/user#custom_profile_attributes) resource and I want to add `custom_profile_attributes` to my variables. In my `vars.tf` file I have:

```
variable "custom_profile_attributes" {
  description = "custom profile attributes"
  type = map(any)
  default = {}
}
```

and in `main.tf`:

```
resource "okta_user" "user" {
  first_name                = var.first_name
  last_name                 = var.last_name
  login                     = var.email
  email                     = var.email
  status                    = var.status
  custom_profile_attributes = var.custom_profile_attributes
}
```

and my `terragrunt.hcl`:

```
inputs = {
  first_name  = title(local.full_name[0])
  last_name   = title(local.full_name[1])
  email       = "${local.full_name[0]}.${local.full_name[1]}@company.com"
  status      = "ACTIVE"
  groups      = [dependency.team.outputs.okta_group_id]
  admin_roles = ["USER_ADMIN"]
  lifecycle = {
    ignore_changes = ["admin_roles"]
  }
  custom_profile_attributes = {
    "tenant_id" : "ssotest",
  }
}
```

and while running `terragrunt apply` I get:

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 7, in resource "okta_user" "user":
│    7:   custom_profile_attributes = var.custom_profile_attributes
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.custom_profile_attributes is a map of dynamic
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "custom_profile_attributes": string
│ required.
```

And I can see that string is required, but even changing type to `string` I get the same error. Can somebody tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jsonencode` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode) for this. The variable would then stay of type `map(any)`, but you would provide it like this:

```
  custom_profile_attributes = {
    tenant_id = "ssotest"
  }
```

Then, in the Okta resource, you would do the following:

```
resource "okta_user" "user" {
  first_name                = var.first_name
  last_name                 = var.last_name
  login                     = var.email
  email                     = var.email
  status                    = var.status
  custom_profile_attributes = jsonencode(var.custom_profile_attributes)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Okta documentation on Custom Attributes](https://help.okta.com/en-us/Content/Topics/users-groups-profiles/usgp-add-custom-user-attributes.htm), the custom attributes schema supports a variety of different data types, where each attribute can have its own type.

In Terraform's type system, `map(any)` means a map of any *single* type -- that is, all elements must have the same type -- so that type constraint seems too strict for what the underlying system is expecting. Instead, it seems like the only hard constraint is that the string represents a JSON *object*, as opposed to any other JSON type.

Terraform's type system doesn't have a direct equivalent of that constraint; we can only specify that a variable requires a *specific* object type, with a fixed set of attributes. So this is a rare example of a situation where it's appropriate to use `type = any` to represent that your module is treating this value as entirely opaque and just passing it on to the remote system, but we can also add a custom validation rule to reject values that aren't of an object type.

With all of that said then, here's one way to write that:

```
variable "custom_profile_attributes" {
  type    = any
  default = {}

  validation {
    # This rule allows anything that would become a JSON object
    # when passed to jsonencode, which seems to match what the
    # Okta provider requires. In practice that means either
    # a Terraform object type or a Terraform map type, since
    # both of those correspond to JSON's object type.
    constraint    = startswith(jsonencode(var.custom_profile_attributes), "{")
    error_message = "Must be an object or map value."
  }
}

resource "okta_user" "user" {
  first_name                = var.first_name
  last_name                 = var.last_name
  login                     = var.email
  email                     = var.email
  status                    = var.status
  custom_profile_attributes = jsonencode(var.custom_profile_attributes)
}
```

This design would then allow a user of your module to pass in any arbitrary Terraform object type, which allows including any number of JSON properties where each property can be of any type that Terraform can serialize as JSON with [`jsonencode`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode).

The module then just passes the JSON representation of that data structure verbatim to the provider.